# How to supply compiler options in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, g++, qmake

I am trying to learn Qt, I have file `test.cpp` that I run via the terminal using the following command:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs libsbml`  test.cpp -L /usr/local/lib -lsbml -lstdc++ -lm
```

How can I suppl the same options to Qt?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the qmake snippet below. In short, you would need to take a look at the following qmake variables:

> [LIBS](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs)
>
> [INCLUDEPATH](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath)
>
> [TEMPLATE](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#template)
>
> [TARGET](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#target)
>
> [HEADERS](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#headers)
>
> [SOURCES](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#sources)
>
> [CONFIG](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qmake-variable-reference.html#config)
>
> PKGCONFIG

#### test.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = test
INCLUDEPATH += .
LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib -lsbml -lstdc++ -lm

unix {
    CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
    PKGCONFIG += libsbml
}

HEADERS += test.h
SOURCES += test.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

In .pro file add:

LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib -lsbml -lstdc++ -lm

look at the Makefile to figure out what variables are used. The makefile is in the build folder made by Qt.

Comment: That's for -l and -L options - you should cover -i and -I (INCLUDEPATH variable) and other options with QMAKE_CPPFLAGS/etc. because the question title is pretty generic. A lot of people use QMAKE_CPPFLAGS to enable C++11 support.

Comment: Also, it does not address the pkgconfig, the HEADERS and SOURCES, etc.

Comment: @JohnChadwick: I think you skipped this, "How can I suppl the same options to Qt?" Note the "same". Obviously, you cannot put this all into the title, so that is fine. :) QMAKE_CPPFLAGS for enabling c++11 is the wong way, fwiw. In fact, that should be set through the CONFIG variable as per documentation.

Comment: In Qt 5 maybe - but before Qt directly supported C++11, you couldn't. So now, if you want to support both w/ C++11, you have to do both. Nonetheless, the question in the question title is a lot more generally useful than the one in the question itself, so I see no reason why a more complete answer is a bad thing.

Comment: @JohnChadwick: if you disregard what the OP wants, do not be surprised if it is calld off-topic. :)

Comment: All I was suggesting is what your answer contains, but maybe with the addition of `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS` (for finer-grained control.) It still answers the question in the body, even without the example - it just doesn't provide source code. I do not think anyone would consider it off-topic. (Not to mention, Stack Overflow promotes good and thorough answers to questions - not _necessarily_ what the original poster wants. See `how-to-ask`.)